# Why is my T-SQL Query returning inconsistent output?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, output, behavior

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

SELECT 
    a.ReservationStayID
    ,c.PMSConfirmationNumber
    ,c.[PropertyCode]
    ,a.StayDate
    ,c.[MTH]
    ,1 AS 'RN'
    ,a.PackagePlanCode
    ,c.[Market Segment Code]
    ,c.[Status]
    ,c.[CurrencyCode]
    ,a.RateAmount
    ,SUM(a.RateAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ReservationStayID) AS 'CUM_Rate'
    ,d.[Exchange Rate]
    ,((a.RateAmount * d.[Exchange Rate]) / 1.15) AS 'Package Revenue Excl VAT'
    ,c.[Tour Operator]
    ,c.[Group Booking ID]
    ,c.[Source of Business]
    ,c.[Booking Origin (1)]
    ,c.[Market FINAL]
    ,ISNULL(ay.[KeyAccountName], 'NA') AS 'Key A/c'
    ,c.[CreatedOn_RSD]
FROM 
    ReservationStayDate a
INNER JOIN 
    [RESERVATIONLIST(2)] c ON c.[ReservationStayID] = a.ReservationStayID
                           AND c.[MTH] = datename(m, StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy, StayDate) AS VARCHAR)
INNER JOIN 
    [PKGREVENUE] d ON d.[ReservationStayID] = a.ReservationStayID
                   AND d.[StayDate] = a.StayDate
ORDER BY 
    a.ReservationStayID;
```

The query runs fine but the output is inconsistent! At times, I get 698,017 rows, and then if I run the query again immediately, I may get 698,020. Another attempt showed 698,025.

This is driving me crazy as my database has not been updated. The SAME query is being run at, say, 1 minute interval and each run is providing an inconsistent output in terms of the number of records! What could be causing this behavior?

I don't know if this additional information will be of any help:

When I the ran the query "as is" above, it gave me 4 records for ReservationStayID = 147469.

I then added the following line to the above query as a filter:

```
WHERE a.ReservationStayID = 147469
```

and surprisingly, I got only 2 rows!

`[ReservationList(2)]` and `[PKGREVENUE]` are views.

Here are the 2 Views which are invloved:

View 1:

```
CREATE VIEW [RESERVATIONLIST(2)] AS

SELECT 
   x.[ReservationStayID],
   b.PropertyCode,
   c.CreatedOn,
   c.CreatedBy,
   c.UpdatedBy,
   c.UpdatedOn,
   xy.Rooms AS [Room Inventory], --added
   (xy.Rooms*[DaysInMonth]) AS [RNAvailable], --added
   (x.[Nights Spent]/(xy.Rooms*[DaysInMonth])) AS [Occupancy],
   c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
   a.ArrivalDate AS [Arrival Date],
   a.DepartureDate AS [Departure Date],
   (a.ArrivalDate - CONVERT(Varchar(10),(CAST(x.CreatedOn as DATE)),(101))) AS 'Booking Lead Time',
    a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
    j.ProfileID,
    j.EmailAddress AS 'Email',
    b.MarketSegmentCode AS 'Market Segment Code',
    a.DateOfBirth AS 'Date of Birth',
    b.ReservationStatus AS 'Status',
    j.Nationality AS 'Nationality',
    k.[Country of Residence],
    ISNULL(g3.CountryGroup2, 'Not Specified') AS 'Country of Residence 2', 
     c.ReasonForStayCode AS 'Reason For Stay',
     b.RateplanCode,
     x.[Rate Plan RSD] AS 'Rate Plan Code',
     x.[Room Type RSD] AS 'Room Type',
     i.RoomType3 AS 'Room Type 3', -- this code converts the Room Type as per Room Type codes used in the Budget
     al.NonRoombundleID,
     k3.MpDescription AS 'Meal Plan Description',
     ISNULL(k3.MpCode,'RO') AS 'Meal Plan Code',
     x.[Adult RSD] AS 'Adult',
     x.[Child RSD] AS 'Child',
     b.GuestCount AS 'Total Guest',
     x.[Nights Spent] AS 'Room Nights',
     x.[MTH],
     x.[DaysInMonth], --added
     x.[Rate] AS 'Room Rate WITH VAT',
     c.CurrencyCode, 
     y.[Pkg Rev (with VAT)],
     y.[Pkg Rev (excl VAT)], 
    x.CreatedOn AS [CreatedOn_RSD],
    CONVERT(Varchar(10),(CAST(x.CreatedOn as DATE)),(101)) as [DATE CREATED ON],
    datename(m,x.CreatedOn) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,x.CreatedOn) as varchar) as [Created On (MTH)],
    x.[DateOfArrival],
    x.[DateOfDeparture],
    e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business',
    c.TAProfileID,
    c.PropGroupBookingID AS 'Group Booking ID', 
    e.Name AS 'Tour Operator', 
    g.CountryGroup AS 'Market', 
    c.TAProfileID2, 
    e2.Name AS 'Booking Origin (1)',
   g2.CountryGroup AS 'Booking Origin (2)', 

   (CASE
     WHEN e.TravelAgencyTypeCode = 'DMC' 
     THEN g2.CountryGroup 
     ELSE g.CountryGroup 
      END) AS 'Market (DMC Classified)',

   (CASE
     WHEN e.TravelAgencyTypeCode = 'DMC' THEN g2.CountryGroup
    WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' AND c.CurrencyCode = 'MUR' THEN 'DB Local'
    WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' THEN 'DB International'
    ELSE g.CountryGroup
    END) AS 'Market FINAL'

   FROM GuestNameInfo a

  JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID =   b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID 
 LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
 LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID2
 LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode = g2.CountryCode

 LEFT JOIN CtyRes h ON h.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN Market g3 ON g3.CountryCode = h.CountryCode

 LEFT JOIN Profile j ON j.ProfileID = c.ProfileID
 LEFT JOIN HotelInventory xy ON xy.PropertyCode = b.PropertyCode 



 LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT 
    min(CountryCode) AS [Country of Residence]
   , min(ProfileID) AS [Profile ID]
   ,min(PostalAddressID) AS [Postal Address ID]

   FROM PostalAddress
   GROUP BY CountryCode,ProfileID,PostalAddressID
  ) k ON k.[Postal Address ID] = c.PostalAddressID


 LEFT JOIN
  (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
     datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(StayDate), StayDate),
          dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(StayDate), StayDate))) AS [DaysInMonth],
     min(adultcount) as 'Adult RSD',
     min(childcount) as 'Child RSD',
     min(RoomTypeCode) AS 'Room Type RSD',
     min(PackagePlanCode) AS 'Rate Plan RSD',
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
    FROM ReservationStayDate
    GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' +  cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar), datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(StayDate), StayDate),
          dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(StayDate), StayDate)))
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID

 LEFT JOIN RoomCat i ON b.PropertyCode = i.Property AND [Room Type RSD] = i.RoomType


   LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) AS [MTH_PKGREV],
       [ReservationStayId], SUM([Package Revenue with VAT]) AS 'Pkg Rev (with VAT)',
       SUM([Package Revenue excl VAT]) AS 'Pkg Rev (excl VAT)'

   FROM PKGREVENUE

   GROUP BY datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar),[ReservationStayId]


   ) y ON y.[ReservationStayId] = b.ReservationStayID AND [MTH] = datename(m,[MTH_PKGREV]) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,[MTH_PKGREV]) as varchar)


  LEFT JOIN
   (
  SELECT ReservationStayID, MTH, NonRoombundleID

  FROM NONROOMBUNDLEID

  group by ReservationStayID, MTH, NonRoombundleID

  )al ON al.ReservationStayID = x.ReservationStayID AND al.[MTH] = x.[MTH]

  LEFT JOIN NonRoomBundle k2 ON K2.NonRoomBundleID = al.NonRoombundleID

  LEFT JOIN MealPlan k3 ON k3.MpDescription = k2.Description


  WHERE a.PrimaryGuest = '+'
```

View 2:

```
CREATE VIEW [PKGREVENUE] AS

SELECT
  ReservationStayDate.ReservationStayID AS [ReservationStayId]
  ,ReservationStay.PMSConfirmationNumber AS [PmsConfirmationNumber]
  ,ReservationStayDate.StayDate AS [StayDate]
  ,ReservationStayDate.RateAmount AS [RateAmount]
  ,ReservationStay.CurrencyCode AS [CurrencyCode]
  ,CAST(ROUND(ISNULL((1/CA.SellRate),1),2) as numeric (36,2)) AS 'Exchange Rate' -- since MUR is not in the Exchange Rate Table, this replaces all NULL values for MUR by 1.00

  ,CAST(ROUND(ReservationStayDate.RateAmount * ISNULL((1/CA.SellRate),1),0) as numeric (36,0)) AS 'Package Revenue with VAT'

  ,(CAST(ROUND(ReservationStayDate.RateAmount * ISNULL((1/CA.SellRate),1),0)/1.15 as numeric (36,0))) AS 'Package Revenue excl VAT'

FROM
  ReservationStayDate
  INNER JOIN ReservationStay ON ReservationStay.ReservationStayID = ReservationStayDate.ReservationStayID

  OUTER APPLY
  (
     SELECT TOP(1) ExchangeRate.SellRate
     FROM ExchangeRate
     WHERE
       ExchangeRate.ToCurrencyCode = ReservationStay.CurrencyCode
       AND ExchangeRate.EffectiveDate <= ReservationStayDate.StayDate
      ORDER BY ExchangeRate.EffectiveDate DESC
  ) AS CA
```

Comment: Either your data is changing or your application is eating/creating rows.

Comment: So, what are the view definitions? Do they make use of any non-deterministic functions?

Comment: Could you be reading uncommitted data?  If you run it as read committed only, do you still see different result amounts?

Comment: Check for triggers which might change the data under the hood

Comment: @Mihai - triggers run in response to database changes (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE). A `SELECT` statement shouldn't be able to invoke any such changes (they're forbidden in e.g. UDFs)

Comment: @dfundako Thanks for your reply. How do I run my query as "read committed"?

Comment: @user3115933 - read committed is the *default*. Unless you've gone out of your way to do something else, it's where you already are. I'd think it *far* more likely that you've got non-determinism happening somewhere. Since it's not evident in the query you've shown, it's likely to be in the view definitions.

Comment: @user3115933 write this at the top of your query:
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

Comment: @dfundako I did what you said regarding SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED but I still get different results when I run the query :-(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your help. I am having a hard time figuring out whether the Views make use of any non-deterministic functions. Any tips on what I should look for in the Views?

Comment: `RAND()`, `NEWID()` or anything datetime related are the most obvious ones.

Comment: Ok. I am editing my post to include the 2 views. Grateful if you could have a look.

Comment: @Frisbee Views posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone who provided help to my problem. I even got a negative and I don't know why! 
Anyway, I would like to provide an update here as to how I solved the problem. I had a deep look into the deterministic and non-deterministic functions as suggested by some of you. However, I could not locate any such functions in my query and views that were causing the main query to misbehave and give inconsistent results.

I gave the GROUP BY clause a try in my main query (although I did not need that clause). And behold, the problem was solved!! Now, my query is giving me the same number of records at each attempt. As to why did the GROUP BY clause solve the problem, I have absolutely no idea. Just wanted to share this with the community here. May be someone can shed some light on the magical powers of the GROUP BY clause! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not all functions in Sql Server are deterministic. Check out [Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

I don't see anything that is non-deterministic in your query but you might want to look at the views that you join on to and make sure that there is nothing there that is in the non deterministic list.

Comment: Thanks. Any tips on what I should look for in the Views to figure out if there is something non deterministic?

Comment: The webpage I linked to has the list. You could post the views if you are not sure.

Comment: Looking over your views I don't see anything obvious. Do these views use any other views or are all the joins to tables? I hope you don't have much data because the first view has far too many joins. I would consider moving some of this logic into the application or not using a view and instead using queries that break up that logic into multiple stages using temp tables. The benefit of the temp tables is that you could more easily identity where the variation is coming from - whether it is due to non-deterministic behaviour or from changing data.

Comment: I don't know if this observation is helpful in finding the issue: If I run the Views as stand-alone queries several times, the results (number of records output) are always the same. Can we conclude that there are no "non-deterministic" issues in the views? If yes, could it be the way the Views are joined to the Main Query?

Answer (score 0):

This always happens when there is a mixed-up or not consistent use of aliases in statements that contain:

```
1-order by
2-group by
3-where clauses
```

Like in this line:

```
GROUP BY datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate)
```

maybe the field `StayDate`  exists in different parts of the query. Sometimes the optimizer takes a different path and chooses the other field. Aliases direct the optimizer always to take the proper field.