# How can I extract all records based on a start date and an end date in the following context?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL SERVER 2014` and I have a table named `GuestInfo` with around 250,000 records in it.

Here is an extract of the `GuestInfo` table:

```
ID    Name       ArrDate        DepDate 
100   P Smith    2013-02-16     2013-02-20
101   A Owen     2013-04-01     2013-04-13
108   M John     2013-04-05     2013-04-08
132   S Walter   2014-06-09     2014-06-11
```

How should I write my `T-SQL` query if I want to extract, say, all guests whose stay include period `2013-04-06` to `2013-04-08`?

So, expected output here is:

```
ID     Name     ArrDate        DepDate
101   A Owen     2013-04-01     2013-04-13
108   M John     2013-04-05     2013-04-08
```

This is just an example. Basically, I want the logic to be implemented for a scenario where I have the flexibility to choose any stay periods based on a Start Date and an End Date. 
Note: The Start Date could be in a different month than the End Date

Comment: It's a simple query with a `WHERE` clause with two (2) conditions. Did you try something? Sorry, but SO isn't a writing code service.

Comment: I suggest looking up `BETWEEN` and parameters. These are quite simple terms on SQL so there's plenty of examples and documentation on it. A Google/Bing/etc will give you everything you need if you're willing to try.

Comment: As a hint: `WHERE ArrDate >= ? AND DepDate <= ?`

Comment: @Larnu Weird things happens on SO, looking to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33736997/6426692) post and the actual question. Oh man hows that happen :/

Comment: @Sami Ok, was a simple logic to implement. But it happens! May be I had my mind on other things and could not really catch the logic in this case. :-)

Comment: @user3115933 Yeah, sometimes it happens ;)

Comment: What if there is a partial overlap?

Comment: Have a look at the information for the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BETWEEN` you can get the expected output:

```
SELECT *
FROM GuestInfo
WHERE (@StartPeriod BETWEEN ArrDate AND DepDate) AND 
      (@EndPeriod BETWEEN ArrDate AND DepDate)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM GuestInfo
WHERE ArrDate <= @StartPeriod AND DepDate >= @EndPeriod
```

Demo with given sample data:

```
DECLARE @GuestInfo TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR (50), ArrDate  DATE, DepDate DATE); 

INSERT INTO @GuestInfo ( ID , Name, ArrDate, DepDate) VALUES
(100, 'P Smith' , '2013-02-16', '2013-02-20'),
(101, 'A Owen'  , '2013-04-01', '2013-04-13'),
(108, 'M John'  , '2013-04-05', '2013-04-08'),
(132, 'S Walter', '2014-06-09', '2014-06-11');

DECLARE @StartPeriod AS DATE = '2013-04-06';
DECLARE @EndPeriod   AS DATE = '2013-04-08';

SELECT *
FROM @GuestInfo
WHERE (@StartPeriod BETWEEN ArrDate AND DepDate) AND 
      (@EndPeriod BETWEEN ArrDate AND DepDate)
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    ArrDate     DepDate
-----------------------------------
101 A Owen  2013-04-01  2013-04-13
108 M John  2013-04-05  2013-04-08
```

Comment: Thanks, Arul. Makes sense!

Comment: @user3115933 Welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!